# Use pipeline parameters in azure data factory copy pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a copy pipeline that reads data from a Netezza table. I use a query to load the rows based on a timestamp, something like

`select * from myTable where creationTs > '2019-10-10T00:00:00'`

Right now the query contains a hardcoded value for the timestamp, I would like to be able to read that value from the pipeline parameters, so I can re-run for different dates without changing the query.
Is it even possible? I tried all sorts of syntaxes, to no avail.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible with pipeline parameters.

- Create a new `pipeline parameter`

[image]

- Access the parameter value with expression like `@{pipeline().parameters.arg1}`

[image]

- Every time you hit run/debug, you will be prompted to enter the value
  for parameters.
- When automating it with triggers, you may pass the parameter value as part of the triggers.